# Trying to use Javascript/CSS to change a property, but can't get it to work within an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So you're my last hope.

I need to create a quiz, that validates name and email. Once the name and email have been validated ONLY THEN will the quiz show up. Thing is, when I put my code of

```
function changeStyle() {

  if (document.getElementById('quiz').style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

in, my if/else statement it doesn't work. Running this code outside of the if/else statement works, albeit simply on the click of a button. The alert in the if/else statement runs as well, as does the rest of script afterwards. It seems to be just ignoring this script. Here is the Jquery i'm using:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
     var input = $(this);
     var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
     var is_name = re.test(input.val());
     if (is_name) {
       input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
     } else {
       input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
     }
   });

   $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
     var input = $(this);
     var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
     var is_email = re.test(input.val());
     if (is_email) {
       input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
     } else {
       input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
     }
   });

   $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event) {
     var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();
     var error_free = true;
     for (var input in form_data) {
       var element = $("#contact_" + form_data[input]['name']);
       var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
       var error_element = $("span", element.parent());
       if (!valid) {
         error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
         error_free = false;
       } else {
         error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
       }
     }
     if (!error_free) {
       event.preventDefault();
     } else {

       alert('This alert is working');

       function changeStyle() {

         if (document.getElementById('quiz').style.display == "none") {
           document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = "block";
         } else {
           document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = "none";
         }
       }



     }
   });

 });
```

CSS:

```
#quiz{
  display:none;
}
```

Please help! I have tried body:onload aswell, but it seems to just have the same issue. And I've already scoured the internet for answers. I seem to be missing something, I just don't know what.

Thanks

EDIT* changeStyle is being called. Here is the HTML relating to this part.

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
<!-- Name -->
<div>
<label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></>
<span class="error">This field is required</span>
</div>
<!-- Email -->
<div>
<label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></>
<span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>               
</div>
<!-- Submit Button -->
<div id="contact_submit">            
<button  type="button" onclick="show()">Submit</button>    </div>

</form>

<content>
<form id="quiz" name="quiz">
<h1>Test your CSS knowledge!</h1>
<h3>What does CSS stand for?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">
<input type="radio" id="q1a1" class="answer"  value="Cascading CSS" data-    correct="false" name="q1" ><label for="q1a1">Cascading Css</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q1b2" class="answer"  value="Cascading Style Sheets" data-correct="true" name="q1"><label for="q1b2">Cascading Style Sheets</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q1c3" class="answer"  value="Cascading Seperate Style" data-correct="false" name="q1"><label for="q1c3">Cascading Separate Style</label><br>
</fieldset>

<h3>Which attribute can be set to bold?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">
<input type="radio" id="q2a1" class="answer"  value="Text Decoration" data-correct="false" name="q2" ><label for="q2a1">Text Decoration</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q2b2" class="answer"  value="Font Style" data-correct="false" name="q2"><label for="q2b2">Font Style</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q2c3" class="answer"  value="Font Weight" data-correct="true" name="q2"><label for="q2c3">Font Weight</label><br>

</fieldset>

<h3>Which tag is used to link an external CSS file?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">

<input type="radio" id="q3a1" class="answer"  value="Script" data-correct="false" name="q3" ><label for="q3a1">Script</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q3b2" class="answer"  value="Link" data-correct="true" name="q3"><label for="q3b2">Link</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q3c3" class="answer"  value="Rel" data-correct="false" name="q3"><label for="q3c3">Rel</label><br>

</fieldset>


<h3>Which attribute sets the underline property?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">

<input type="radio" id="q4a1" class="answer"  value="Font Style" data-correct="false" name="q4" ><label for="q4a1">Font Style</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q4b2" class="answer"  value="Text Decoration" data-correct="true" name="q4"><label for="q4b2">Text Decoration</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q4c3" class="answer"  value="Font Weight" data-correct="false" name="q4"><label for="q4c3">Font Weight</label><br>

</fieldset>

<h3>Which element is NOT relative?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">

<input type="radio" id="q5a1" class="answer"  value="Px" data-correct="true" name="q5" ><label for="q5a1">Px</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q5b2" class="answer"  value="Cm" data-correct="false" name="q5"><label for="q5b2">Cm</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q5c3" class="answer"  value="%"  data-correct="false" name="q5"><label for="q5c3">%</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q5d4" class="answer"  value="Em" data-correct="false" name="q5"><label for="q5d4">Em</label><br>

</fieldset>

<h3>Which element IS relative?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">

<input type="radio" id="q6a1" class="answer"  value="Em" data-correct="true" name="q6" ><label for="q6a1">Em</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q6b2" class="answer"  value="Cm" data-correct="false" name="q6"><label for="q6b2">Cm</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q6c3" class="answer"  value="MM" data-correct="false" name="q6"><label for="q6c3">MM</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q6d4" class="answer"  value="Inch" data-correct="false" name="q6"><label for="q6d4">Inch</label><br>

</fieldset>

<h3>What attribute is used to move an elements content away from its border?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">


<input type="radio" id="q7a1" class="answer"  value="Margin" data-correct="false" name="q7" ><label for="q7a1">Margin</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="q7b2" class="answer"  value="Padding" data-correct="true" name="q7"><label for="q7b2">Padding</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q7c3" class="answer"  value="Border" data-correct="false" name="q7"><label for="q7c3">Border</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q74d" class="answer"  value="Width" data-correct="false" name="q7"><label for="q7d4">Width</label><br>  
</fieldset>

<h3>Which element does not contribute to a block elements total width?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">
<input type="radio" id="q8a1" class="answer"  value="Width" data-correct="false" name="q8" ><label for="q8a1">Width</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q8b2" class="answer"  value="Border" data-correct="false" name="q8"><label for="q8b2">Border</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q8c3" class="answer"  value="Background-image" data-correct="true" name="q8"><label for="q8c3">Background-image</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q8d4" class="answer"  value="Padding" data-correct="false" name="q8"><label for="q8d4">Padding</label><br>
</fieldset>


<h3>Which property changes positioned elements display order?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">
<input type="radio" id="q9a1" class="answer" value="Width" data-correct="false" name="q9" ><label for="q9a1">Width</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q9b2" class="answer"  value="Background" data-correct="false" name="q9"><label for="q9b2">Background</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q9c3" class="answer"  value="z-index" data-correct="true" name="q9"><label for="q9c3">Z-index</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q9d4" class="answer"  value="Azimuth" data-correct="false" name="q9"><label for="q9d4">Azimuth</label><br>
</fieldset>


<h3>Which value of background-repeat will cause the background to repeat vertically?</h3>
<fieldset class="question">
<input type="radio" id="q10a1" class="answer"  value="repeat-x" data-correct="false" name="q10" ><label for="q10a1">repeat-x</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q10b2" class="answer"  value="repeat" data-correct="false" name="q10"><label for="q10b2">repeat</label><<br>
<input type="radio" id="q10c3" class="answer"  value="repeat-y" data-correct="true" name="q10"><label for="q10c3">repeat-y</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="q10d4" class="answer"  value="No-repeat" data-correct="false" name="q10"><label for="q10d4">No-repeat</label><br>

</fieldset>
<footer>

<fieldset class="calc-percentage" name="score">
<input type="button" id="calc"  value="Get score" />
<div>
<p><label for="percentage">Score = </label><input type=text size=15 id="percentage" name="percentage" /></p>
<input type="submit" onclick="checkQuiz()">
</div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Your code is missing some close brackets. Look at your `if (!error_free) else` block

Comment: You should really indent your code properly. You'd be able to see errors like this easily: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: you never call `changeStyle()` so why would it execute?

Comment: Well you guys are quick. I've only learnt Javascript/Jquery in the last month. Will have a go at creating a fiddle. And I do call changeStyle() in the HTML as a button.

Comment: In regards to the errors, sorry, new at this. Regardless fixing those errors still produces the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: if you've got access to jQuery effects, why not just use `.toggle()` - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hey Klors. New to javascript, but wouldn't .toggle() switch between display:none and display:block? I just want it to be display: none until I click a button, which would change the display to block and stay that way.

Comment: For `$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name'])` to work your Element `name` and `id` would have to be the same on every input. Won't work if your using radio buttons.

Comment: AHhhhhh ok. So, would I be able to go about this another way, say using  body:onload with the quiz having a display:none. If so how would I go about that.

Answer (score 0):

You only redefine `function changeStyle(){}`, never calling it. Also, if you're going to use jQuery then use it. Just use `.css()`, if you don't want to `.toggle()`. Get rid of `onclick='changeStyle()'` in your HTML.

Despite all of your other possible errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contact_name').on('input', function(){
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    var is_name = re.test(input.val());
    if(is_name){
      input.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    else{
     input.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
  });
  $('#contact_email').on('input', function(){
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var is_email = re.test(input.val());
    if(is_email){
      input.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    else {
     input.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
  });
  $('#contact_submit button').click(function(event){
    var form_data = $('#contact').serializeArray(), error_free = true;
    for(var input in form_data){
      var element = $('#contact_' + form_data[input]['name']);
      var valid = element.hasClass('valid');
      var error_element = $('span', element.parent());
      if(!valid){
        error_element.removeClass('error').addClass('error_show');
        error_free = false;
      }
      else{
        error_element.removeClass('error_show').addClass('error');
      }
    }
    if(!error_free){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
      // look what changed here - you have to call a function to execute it
      $('#quiz').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
});
```

Again get rid of your regular JavaScript function `changeStyle()` and remove it from HTML, as well!!!

Comment: Hi PHPglue. Thanks for the answer. Maybe I didn't say it clear enough in the question. I have called it in the HTML as a button. Sorry I didn't mention I'd tried it the Jquery way too, just thought trying it plain javascript might help. However I will implement your suggestions and I'll go from there.

Comment: For a more generically useful function, set it back to empty string/remove the display style, rather than setting to block.

Comment: Hi PHPglue, I've changed it back to Jquery and call it using the button with onclick="changeStyle()" but it just does the same thing.

Comment: It could be a problem with HTML somewhere else on your page. Also, check your console in firebug.

Comment: Just to clarify, This code does work. When I click on the button containing onclick='changeStyle' it does change the style of the quiz from none to block, so the quiz comes up. That bit of code works. What doesn't work is when I take this same code and put it in the else statement, so that theoretically if the person has typed in their name and email, it should run this  bit of code, just like it does outside of the if/else statement. Thats about the gist of it. You're saying that because I've used radio buttons this wont work? Well I'm stuck haha.

Comment: I don't see any radio buttons. Also, I don't see any Element with `id='contact_submit_button'`. If you are using that jQuery then you should use the correct Element, and you don't need `onclick` as an HTML attribute.

Comment: I'll just post my entire HTML in then so you can see the full picture.

Comment: `$('#contact_submit>button').click(function(){})`. Get used to not putting Events into HTML. Again, remove `onclick='changeStyle()'`. It works because it's separate. Your condition is in your jQuery, and your function is not called in there.

Comment: It's simply not working. Thanks for the effort though, I will continue to try with your suggestions. Either that or I'll do body onload. Thanks so much!

Comment: I redid my post. You have to understand the difference between defining and calling functions.